# Удаление класса из его метода

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс

```
class Cat:
  a = 10

  def inc_del(self):
    self.a += 1
    del self
```

Далее я хочу, чтобы при вызове метода класса `inc_del()` экземпляр класса удалился, но этого не происходит.

```
b = Cat()
b.inc_del()
b
>>> <__main__.Cat object at ...>
```

Что я в данном случае сделал не так? Разве я не могу удалить класс в его методе?

Answer (score 2):

В питоне объекты удаляются автоматически при сборке мусора, когда на объект не остается ссылок. Инструкция del может удалить ссылку (переменную) на объект, а сам объект останется в памяти пока не будет уничтожен сборщиком мусора. Описанная функция **inc_del** пытается у экземпляра класса удалить ссылку на сам экземпляр, а не класс.

Comment: Кажется, я понял. А как вы предложите сделать то, что я хочу? У меня появилась идея передать в inc_del(b) и вместо del self написать del b?

Comment: А что хотите получить? если хотите удалить экземпляр, просто пишите del b

Answer (score 1):

`del` в Питоне удаляет имена или ссылки из контейнера. Эта конструкция не удаляет объекты. В Питоне нет конструкций, которые бы объекты удаляли. При отсутствии ссылок, система сборки мусора может удалить на каком-то этапе объект, но это зависит от реализации (как и когда и освобождается ли вообще память) и может меняться от версии к версии.

`del self` удаляет локальное для метода `inc_del` имя. Это бессмысленно делать (при выходе из метода, можно считать что локальное пространство не существует).

Вопрос похож на [XY-задачу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044): следует определить, какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить попыткой удаления объекта вызовом его метода и лу́чшее решение выбрать (ничего не делать: не пытаться вручную управлять памятью в Питоне, удалить неиспользуемые объекты из контейнера, использовать слабые ссылки, итд в зависимости от конкретной задачи).